# Modifying DataGrid cell values on CellEditEnding event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I've been trying to change a different cell value in same row inside CellEditEnding eventhandler in WPF DataGrid control.

If I edit the cell value in an existing row, it works as expected. However, when adding a new row, the change is not reflected to UI if another cell value is clicked by mouse without going into edit mode.

Moving focus to next cell by pressing tab also works as expected, but shouldn't it work for clicking aswell?

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
    DataRow existingRow = dataTable.NewRow();
    dataTable.Rows.Add(existingRow);

    this.MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
    this.MyDataGrid.CellEditEnding += MyDataGrid_CellEditEnding;
}

void MyDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    (e.Row.Item as DataRowView).Row[1] = "a string that should be displayed immediatly";
}
```

So far I've tried to change binding UpdateSourceTrigger, NotifyOnSourceUpdated and NotifyOnTargetUpdated but nothing seems to work. I've also tried to do according fixing by reading related topics : http://codefluff.blogspot.fi/2010/05/commiting-bound-cell-changes.html

But those doesn't seem to help either..

One way that I've found to be working is following snippet:

```
var frameworkElement = this.MyDataGrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(e.Row);
frameworkElement.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "a string that should be displayed immediatly");
```

but I wouldn't want to do dependency on dependencyproperties as I might not know the underlying display type.

So the question is that what could I do to achieve UI updation in new rows as it works with existing rows without using the provided second code snippet? I feel I am missing something..

Edit : Using ClipboardPaste will also work for setting new value but the original edited value will be lost for some reason.

Edit2 : The xaml is currently plain DataGrid, I've tried to do columns and their bindings manually but as I haven't got them to work I've removed them to keep the example code simple

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" />
```

Edit3 : Added this image to describe the problem better. So after clicking next cell I would like the text to be displayed
[Example image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbhc3.jpg)

Edit4 : Using snoop to view the cell seems to set the element visible, also calling .UpdateTarget(); for the binding seems to help, but it's not working automaticly. Still wondering what is the cause..

Edit5: I would like this to work with DataTable as I need it's other features

Comment: You could use the pasting mechanism: column.OnPastingCellClipboardContent( Items[ i ],"invisible string" );

Comment: That seems to change the second cell value, but now the original cell edit is lost, hence feels a bit hacky. Thanks for commenting though, it might be that there actually isn't any nice way of doing this :/

Comment: @user5677774 can you publish your XAML code please?

Comment: @Ilan Added xaml code as requested

Comment: Now i actually understand what you want... Create a DatagridTemplateColumn and handle this special behavior in your CellTemplate, e.g. CellEditTemplate is a Textbox, CellTemplate is a TextBlock which displays "invisible string" . In case you can't create your own columns, just store your original value in an attached property

Comment: @SnowballTwo Hmm, I am not sure if I understood so I updated the question to be more describing. The cell element seems to be TextBlock as default in viewing mode and TextBox in edit mode. I can create own columns if needed, but I don't know kind of special behaviour I should do in it. 

One thing that I noticed that if I go ahead and display the DataGridCell element in Snoop then the text appears in UI, so the code seems to be correct but something else isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing huge amount of different kind of solutions I ended up adding the row when starting to edit a cell. As the feature I was seeking was working in existing rows it did fix the problem.

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnBeginningEdit(DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBeginningEdit(e);
        this.CommitEdit();
    }

    protected override void OnCellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellEditEnding(e);
        (e.Row.Item as DataRowView).Row[1] = "a string that should be displayed immediatly";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the MVVM way and then you will meet your requirements by a built-in notification mechanism of WPF itself, where on upfdate of some property in data context you can trigger update of another property. Example: 
 1. Xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridSoHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dataGridSoHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:DataGridSoHelpAttempt"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <dataGridSoHelpAttempt:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}"/>
</Grid></Window>
```

2. View model code:

```
public class MainViewModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        DataSource = new ObservableCollection<BaseData>(new List<BaseData>
        {
            new BaseData {Name = "John"},
            new BaseData {Name = "Ron"},
            new BaseData {Name = "Bob"},
        });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<BaseData> DataSource { get; set; }
}
```

3. Model code:

```
public class BaseData:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    private string _description;

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            Description = "a string that should be displayed immediatly";
        }
    }

    public virtual object Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            _description = (string) value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

4. BaseObservableObject a basic INotifyPropertyChanged implementation:

```
public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

5. Please keep in mind that your model's properties objects can be complex (like images or classes that describe another view models) but in this case you have to template your data grid columns or/and cells (example link: [WPF DataGrid Control](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html)).

I'll really happy to help in case you'll have problems with code.
Regards

**Update**
 1. Code behind - you should update DataTable, but please take in account that update have to be performed on row that already exists in Table:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly DataTable _dataTable;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.MyDataGrid.CellEditEnding += MyDataGrid_CellEditEnding;
        _dataTable = new DataTable();
        _dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
        _dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
        DataRow existingRow = _dataTable.NewRow();
        _dataTable.Rows.Add(existingRow);

        this.MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = _dataTable.DefaultView;

    }


    void MyDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataRowView = (e.Row.Item as DataRowView);
        var columnIndex = e.Column.DisplayIndex;
        var rowIndex = e.Row.GetIndex();
        var dv = _dataTable.DefaultView;
        var nextColumnIndex = columnIndex + 1;
        if (dv.Table.Columns.Count <= nextColumnIndex || dv.Table.Rows.Count <= rowIndex) return;
        dv.Table.Rows[rowIndex][nextColumnIndex] = "a string that should be displayed immediatly";
    }
}
```

2. Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="GridViewWitaFDataTableSoHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" />
</Grid></Window>
```

Comment: Thank you really much for your detailed answer. However I am still facing problems in integrating these changes into target project. I am using a DataTable.DefaultView to display data (for many of its features), hence I cannot(?) implement INotifyPropertyChanged without reimplementing whole DataTable. I think that in DataTable the propertychanged is done somehow rowwise(?), which is the way I would like to go as I am using dynamic data from datatable. Do you have any idea how could I achieve same functionality with using DataTable?Sorry for not mentioning that in the init

Comment: The original problem is that I cannot get the same functionality with new rows than old rows. I feel that there has to be a way to change this value even the row is not in the table at that point of time.

Comment: @user5677774 try to use another event.